# Twitter Streaming filter API: getting IOE exception on a regular basis

Tags: c#, twitter, streaming

I am using twitter streaming API (C#) and getting IOE exception on a regular basis (every 12 hrs or something like that) while Stream reader is trying to read JSON object(readLine). Please look into the exception & the code below. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection ?failed because connected host has failed to respond.

```
string userName = "XXXX";
string password = "XXXX";
string url = @"https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json";
string parameters = "follow=" + userIds  +"&track=" + keywords;

// Request and Response 
HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;
StreamReader streamReader = null;
byte[] byteArray;

// Establishing connection with twitter filter.json
byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
webRequest.Timeout = 100000;

Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] postData = encode.GetBytes(parameters);
webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;
Stream twitterPost = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
twitterPost.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
twitterPost.Close();

webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), encode);

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

while (sw.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromDays(365))
{
    String json = streamReader.ReadLine(); // [The program stop here. throws exception]
    if (json == "")
    {
     continue;
    }
    Packet dataPacket = new Packet() { json = json, id = id++ };
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Execute), dataPacket);
 }

// Aborting the request and closing the stream
webRequest.Abort();
sw.Stop();
streamReader.Close();
streamReader = null;
webResponse.Close();
webResponse = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your internet connection dropped or your connection to your router.

In my country most ISP's refresh your ip address daily at midnight, that creates a connection drop for a few seconds, perhaps your ISP is doing something similar?